# China/Mongolia/Russia by rail with different passports

Tags: customs-and-immigration, paperwork, dual-nationality, russia, mongolia

I'm thinking of traveling from Beijing to Moscow by rail but I want to clear up some visa issues first. With my American passport and Chinese visa I have no problem entering China or Mongolia. However, I'd like to enter Russia using my Venezuelan passport, which offers visa-free entry for 90 days. Will I be permitted to exit Mongolia with my US passport and enter Russia with my Venezuelan passport?

Answer (score 5):

In general yes: it's ok to use one passport for country A and another for country B. Most border crossings consist actually of two independent check points: exit from country A (staffed and operated by country A) and entry into country B (staffed and operated by country B).

Check point A will process your exit and you should use the same passport that you have used to enter country A.  Check point B will process your entry into country B and you can use a different passport for this. In many cases A really doesn't care what happens at B and vice versa.

CAVEAT: While I have done this a few times and never had problems, every combination of passport and border control point is different and may be governed by different local rules. I have no actual knowledge of your specific case and I recommend contacting the consulates for specific advice.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do this. However, many countries' border officers, on exit, will check your paperwork for the bordering country. If the Mongolians know US citizens need a visa for Russia, just show them your Venezuelan passport and explain that it's visa-exempt (they're unlikely to speak any English though, so knowing a little Mongolian or Russian will help)